# Where comes prefix jms.queue/ jms.topic from?

Tags: java, activemq-artemis

I migrated my java spring-boot project from apache activemq to artemis.

I changed all relevant classpaths to artemis.jms.client, but somehow when I start the application, there will be topics with a prefix created like the following:

**jms.topic.VirtualTopic.name**

I just don't know where this **jms.topic** comes from. Does anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ActiveMQ Artemis was designed from the ground up to be a multi-protocol broker. JMS queues and topics were differentiated from resources for other APIs and protocols by their use of the prefixes `jms.queue.` and `jms.topic.` respectively. However, as broker began to support more and more protocols this differentiation was identified as a hindrance to integration rather than an aid. Therefore in early 2017 with the release of version 2.0.0 the prefixes were removed.

You must be using a 1.x version (either of the broker or the client) which is quite old at this point. The current version is 2.14.0. I recommend you move to a more recent release.